# Windows 10 Linux Subsystem Redis not auto-starting

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, redis

I have installed Redis on Windows 10 Linux Subsystem. I followed the instructions available at https://redis.io/topics/quickstart and I have taken care that I followed all the steps mentioned in section [Installing Redis more properly](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart#installing-redis-more-properly) correctly.

However trying to run the following command

```
sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults
```

I am getting following error:

```
~$ sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults
insserv: warning: script 'K01redis_6379' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'redis_6379' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cron'
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'friendly-recovery' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
```

Manually starting the server works:

```
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start
Starting Redis server...
~$ redis-cli ping
PONG
```

Can anybody please help me in configuring Redis on WLS so that it automatically starts in background like it is the case on actual Ubuntu machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here are my instructions on how I have configured redis to start as background task on Windows startup.

1. Install WSL (this is tested with Ubuntu 18.04 version)
2. Install redis-server inside WSL:

   ```
   sudo apt install redis-server
   ```
3. Add sudo permission to your user to execute service command without password Open sudoers file sudo visudo and add to end:

   ```
   your_username ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service redis-server
   ```

   or if you want to disable sudo passwords generally add this to the end:

   ```
   your_username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
   ```
4. Create vbs file e.g. start-redis.vbs inside startup folder (Open Run and enter shell:startup)

   In vbs file insert following:

   ```
   Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   oShell.Run "wsl", 0
   oShell.Run "bash -c ""sudo service redis-server start --daemonize yes"""
   ```

That's it. You can try it by running vbs script and then run htop inside WSL terminal. You should see that redis is running.

I have posted these instructions [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/cromat/a065136db5bdc40f21dc139567ad0340).

Comment: To make the 3. option work with limited right I had to add `--daemonize yes` at the end. ie `your_username ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service redis-server --daemonize yes`

Answer (score 0):

1. you can wait for the next release of Windows or install the insider-build that supports background services https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/04/background-task-support-in-wsl/
2. you can install the windows redis service (no Linux subsystem needed)
   https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis Personal experience was, this works fine for a single test instance, but has major headaches trying to create a reliable cluster.
3. run a Linux instance either as VM or on a separate server.

If this is a developer instance to test code go with 2 or 3. If it is a production deployment and you are expecting to run a cluster then 3.
WSL is create for running small scripts, testing things but I have not found it very friendly as a replacement for Linux server. YMMV